# AWS Cloud front - check distribution's traffic by API before disabling

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have a list of AWS Cloudfront distributions and some of them use a default certificate.
I want to disable these distributions, but first i want to make sure that these distributions are not in use.
I would like to accomplish it with API/SDK, how can i do that ?
Is there a standard way to verify that the distribution is not accessed at all ?
I was thinking of some how to use the cloudFront logging capability, but it provides logs with irrelevant data.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/logging.html

is there a simple way to do it ? say a query to AWS that tell me how many requests were made to a specific distribution in a given time interval.

Answer (score 1):

If you have logs enabled you can query Athena by hosts or distribution id to find out how many requests are made to particular distribution
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html

Or you can look at the monitoring section of the Cloudfront where it shows number of requests by going to Monitoring section of cloudfront in Admin console.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitoring-using-cloudwatch.html